# Javascript - How to fill one date box with incremented date from another?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

I have three date fields for a travel insurance form.  Date one is the depart date, date two is the return date.  The third date is the 'effective date' - this is for clients with an annual plan.  The way this works is a client pre-pays for a trip length over the entire year.  Lets say 30 days.  They can they take as many 30 day trips or less as they like with no additional fees on their insurance plan.

In short the effective date is ALWAYS the Departure Date + X number of days input by the user.

So quite simply what I want to know how to do with Java is this:

Take the date value formatted as MM-DD-YYYY in Box 1, increment it by some number, input that number into Box 2.

Comment: I think you mean Javascript everywhere you say Java :/

Comment: Sorry, don't mean to be a nag, I edited the tags to say javascript and yes you do say Java in the body as well. Hope you find a good solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Date object in JavaScript.

If you do getTime on date object you get timestamp in ms so you can add the offset days in ms and get the other 2 dates.

For example

```
var dt = new Date();

var dt2 = new Date(dt.getTime() + 86400000 * numdays);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp